# c# Get Extern IP using WebRequest Take a Long time

Tags: c#

My Method : it basically return extern IPadress

```
public static string Get_IP()
{
    string url = "http://checkip.dyndns.org";
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    string response = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    string[] a = response.Split(':');
    string a2 = a[1].Substring(1);
    string[] a3 = a2.Split('<');
    string a4 = a3[0];
    return a4;
}
```

I Couldnt understand why My method take a long time to Load the IpAdress , and sometimes it return it instantly !

***ps : I checked My Internet connection it works perfectly and i don't think its a connection speed problem !***

Thank you !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794413/get-endpoint-ip-from-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this piece of code it's going to be fast

```
           string externalip = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");
           Console.WriteLine(externalip);
```

Comment: @CruDy Accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Could you add an explanation for future reference?